# Function overloading - order of definitions

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a library which has some complex `resolve` function, that calls a simple `foo` function. The `resolve` function should work for any type for which `foo` is overloaded.

The `foo` provided in the library works with some basic types, but I want the user to be able to provide its own, overloaded versions of `foo` that could be used in `resolve`.

Here is a very short example:

```
//IN THE LIBRARY
#include <iostream>

void foo(int i) { std::cout << "int " << i; }
void foo(float f) { std::cout << "float " << f; }

template <typename T>
void resolve(T arg) {
    //some complex computation
    foo(arg);
    //some more complutation
}

//IN THE USER CODE

void foo(const char* c) { std::cout << "cstring " << c; }

int main() {
    resolve(3);
    resolve(4.2f);
    resolve("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that the user-defined overload for `foo` appears after the definition of `resolve` and it is not seen. I was expecting that at the time of instantiation `resolve<const char*>` the 3-rd overload of `foo` would be seen – but that is seems not to be the case:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void resolve(T) [with T = const char*]’:
prog.cpp:16:15:   required from here
prog.cpp:8:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  foo(arg);
  ~~~^~~~~
prog.cpp:3:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(int)’
 void foo(int i) { std::cout << "int " << i; }
      ^~~
```

So, my question is, how can I make it work? Is there some easy way of having parts of `resolve` to be user-provided (e.g. in terms of `foo` overloading)?

Some constraints:

- I want it to be resolved at compile-time.
- It should be as simple as possible in user code. For example, having `resolve` take an additional lambda parameter – which should always be the same for a given type of `arg` – is too complex in use.

The use scenario is similar to overloading the `std::less` for given custom `T`, and then using `std::sort` without taking any additional arguments, besides the array of `T` that should be sorted.

Comment: Is there a point of resolve beyond how it is used here? As it is, it just prevents overloading that the compiler could already do, based on your example.

Comment: If the user-defined `foo` is declared before the include of your library, does it work?

Comment: @PhilM I don't understand your first question? There is a point for the existence of `resolve`, it does some complex work. But I cut it out to make the example simple. `foo` could be defined before the inclusion of a library, and this might work, but you don't normally put any code before the `#include` directives, do you?

Comment: Sure, people normally put code (in other include files) before includes all the time :) You'd just require your users to include a header file declaring other overloads before including your header file. Bit messy, perhaps.

Comment: @PhilM "Bit messy"? Rather "untenable" I would say. Depending on include ordering is always horrifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules regarding name lookups in templates are detailed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> For a dependent name used in a template definition, the lookup is postponed until the template arguments are known, at which time ADL examines function declarations [...] that are visible from the template definition context as well as in the template instantiation context, while non-ADL lookup only examines function declarations [...] that are visible from the template definition context (**in other words, adding a new function declaration after template definition does not make it visible except via ADL**).

There are thus two options for you:

- Users can only invoke your `resolve` with arguments that either have the specialization provided by you (by default) or that can be found via [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Basically, they must define their overloads in the same namespace as the types they pass.

  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/KCaO-s
- You make `foo` a template which users can specialize. You provide your own (default) specializations, the user can later provide theirs and `resolve` will choose the best template specialization available *at the point of instantiation* for `resolve` (i.e. where `resolve` is called).

  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/AYn7FM

---

*Addendum:*
The standard library has a very similar problem; see e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) for how customizing e.g. `std::swap` behavior by users is achieved (as in, allowed). Note in particular that with C++20, function template specializations are no longer allowed (only class template specializations). The reasons for that are detailed in [the corresponding paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0551r1.pdf). While the above advice is more comfortable for users than requiring class specializations everywhere, you should probably look into the reasons why the standard library decided to take a more extreme stance.

Comment: So, there is no way to force using a second-phase lookup on `foo`? After all, overloading does depend on the argument being `T`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof `foo(arg)` is dependent, declaration visible at template definition are considered and those that are visible at instantiation context if ADL were to be used.

Comment: @MaxLanghof With the links regarding std function template specializaiton in C++20 - they want to prohibit that and force users to use a more verbose solution with more boilerplate code. I wonder why they can't just change how function overloading works in C++20 instead...

Comment: @CygnusX1 You're free to make a proposal how function overloading should work in your eyes. Do consider the impacts on existing code and the usability in templated libraries though. I agree that the C++20 way will involve annoying amounts of boilerplate, but the existing overloading rules aren't just randomly thrown together. It's a pretty fine-tuned machinery, you can't just "change how it works" that easily.